# Динамическое создание jar'ов в Ant

Tags: ant, java

Добрый день.

Как сделать build, который бы собирал jar-файлы на основе структуры/содержимого папки: 1 файл.class ->  1 файл.jar?

Answer (score 1):

Очень странная хотелка... Ну раз хотелка то почему бы и нет.

Надо взять (установить) [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) - расширенный набор тасков для ant и написать что-то типа (надо тестировать - главное идея):

```
<for param="file">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="*.class"/>
  </path>
  <sequential>
    <jar destfile="${file}.jar"
       includes="${file}"
    />  
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<for param="file">
 <path>
  <fileset dir="${bin}" includes="**/*.class"/>
 </path>
 <sequential>
  <propertyregex property="file.name" override="yes" 
                      input="@{file}"
                      regexp=".*\\(.*)\.class"  
                      select="\1"
                      casesensitive="true" />
  <jar destfile="${jar.dest}/${file.name}.jar" basedir="${bin}"   includes="**/${file.name}.class" >
  </jar>        
 </sequential>
</for>
```

1)Вот что получилось. Проперть нужно заранее описать правда: <property name="file.name" value="ERROR!"/> - с таким значением в логе сразу будет видно если ошибка в regexp.

2)По ant-contrib: раздел installation у них не корректный, нужно брать не "ant-contrib-0.3.jar"(в нём класса для for вообще нет), а "ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"(например). Также, в <taskdef> нужно указывать не "antcontrib.properties"(опять же там for не описан), а "antlib.xml".

3)Barmaley, спасибо за наводку :-) Хотелка позволит автоматизировать то, что бывало по "100 раз" в день руками делалось.